# I am stuck trying to retrieve images from Firebase to my Vue application

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage

I am testing out a Vue application where users should be able to upload an image to Firebase, and once that image is uploaded, it should be saved into the template inside an img tag.

I have no problems uploading the images, but I can't figure out how to retrieve them and make them appear inside the application.

I tried copy-pasting a method I found here on Stack, but it is not working for me.

I also tried searching various tutorials, but all of them only focus on the upload part.

Could anyone help me out?

UPDATE:

I managed to get a preview of the uploaded image to show by changing the `v-for` from `file` to `imgURL`, but I am still facing problems.

The image is STILL not saved to the template. When I press the upload button, the image appears as a preview 130 times on the page, but vanishes when I refresh the page.

```
<template>
<div>
    <h2>image upload</h2>
    <input type="file" @change="uploadImage" value="upload" id="fileButton" ref="myFiles">
    <div class="image_section_content" fluid v-for="files in file" :key="files.id">
        <b-img :src="this.imgURL" fluid alt="Responsive image"></b-img>
        <progress max="100" :value="value" id="uploader">0%</progress>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import db from '@/firebase/init'
import firebase from 'firebase'
export default {
  name: 'ImageUpload',
  data () {
    return {
      value: 0,
      fileButton: document.querySelector("#fileButton"),
      file: [],
      imgRef: null,
      imgURL: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    uploadImage(e){

    //get file
    this.file = this.$refs.myFiles.files[0]

    console.log(this.file)

    //create storageref

    let storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/');

    //save image reference

    this.imgRef = storageRef.fullPath;
    
    //upload file

    let task = storageRef.put(this.file);

    task.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
      let percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
      this.value = percentage;

      snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
         (DownloadURL) => {
            this.imgURL = DownloadURL;

            console.log(this.imgURL)
         }
      )
    })
  },
  // Output image
    mounted() {
    const id = this.$route.params.id;
    const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('images/');

    storageRef.get().then(doc => {
        if (doc.exists) {
            console.log(doc.data()) 
            this.imgURL = doc.data().imgURL
        } else {
            console.log('no data')
        }
    }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
    })
  }
}
```

}

Comment: Have you debugged your method to get the image and seeing what goes on there?

Comment: Do you get the correct image URL in the `imgURL` variable?

Comment: I tried looking in the console. The image is succesfully uploaded to the images folder in my Firebase storage, but I am not getting any output in the application. I am getting no errors in the console.

Comment: `<b-img :src="imgURL" fluid alt="Responsive image"></b-img>` no need to add `this` in src

Answer (score 0):

In this case, create an imgUrl collection in firestore and save the image URL in that collection and call them in the created()hook.

```
  task.on('state_changed', (snapshot) => {
                let percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
                this.value = percentage;

                snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then(
                    (DownloadURL) => {
                        this.imgURL = DownloadURL;

                        db.collection("imgUrl").add({
                         url: this.imgurl
                         })
                    }
                )
            })
```